# Get the value of DataProperty from owl by dotNetRDF

Tags: owl, dotnetrdf

I have a .owl file generated by Protege. (rdf/xml)
I have some individuals and I want to get the value of the DataProperty "hasAge".

```html
  <owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&untitled-ontology-23;a1a">
    <untitled-ontology-23:hasAge rdf:datatype="&xsd;int">12</untitled-ontology-23:hasAge>
    <untitled-ontology-23:isPartOf rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-23;A123" />
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&untitled-ontology-23;a1" />
    <rdfs:comment>张三</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:comment>like</rdfs:comment>
    <rdfs:isDefinedBy>mike</rdfs:isDefinedBy>
    <rdfs:label>gaga</rdfs:label>
    <rdfs:label>zeze</rdfs:label>
  </owl:NamedIndividual>
```

How can I get the value "12" (the value of hasAge)  by using Ontology API or other ways?

Thanks for answering!!!

Comment: And I would be appreciate if you can tell me how to create a new owl individual with DataProperty "hasAge" and value like "24", then write  it in the owl file.

Answer (score 0):

With the [Ontology API](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/2.7.x/user_guide/Ontology-API.html) only a small number of generic properties are directly exposed for individuals. To access your ontology-specific properties you need to access the triples in the graph more directly.

If you don't have the [Individual](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/2.7.x/api/VDS.RDF.Ontology.Individual.html) instance for the resource already then it might be simplest to use the lower-level [IGraph](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/2.7.x/api/VDS.RDF.IGraph.html) operations instead like this:

```cs
var ageTriple = g.GetTriplesWithSubjectPredicate(
      g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://example.org/a1a")),
      g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://example.org/hasAge")))
    .FirstOrDefault();
    var ageNode = ageTriple.Object.AsValuedNode();
    var age = ageNode.AsInteger();
```

If you do already have the Individual, you can use its [Resource](https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/2.7.x/api/VDS.RDF.Ontology.OntologyResource.html#VDS_RDF_Ontology_OntologyResource_Resource) property rather than having to create a UriNode for the first parameter:

```cs
var ageTriple = g.GetTriplesWithSubjectPredicate(
      individual.Node,
      g.CreateUriNode(UriFactory.Create("http://example.org/hasAge")))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**NOTE** As your sample snippet doesn't show what namespace your ontology uses, I have used `http://example.org/` as the namespace in the example above - you will need to replace this with the current namespace URI.

Comment: Thank you Kal!     I have tried method GetLiteralProperty() for a whole afternoon, while I still can't get the value of DataProperty 'hasAge' from individual 'a1a'.      Can you show me the detail of codes? Thank you!

Comment: My apologies @JavaWang97! I had misunderstood what the Ontology API provides access to. I've edited my answer to address accessing the ontology-specific properties of the named individual.